# CSS does not work with framed url on port 8080

Tags: css, url, import, dns, port

I have a home server listening on port `8080` and a URL Frame DNS record that points to **`myserveripaddress:8080`**.
The home page and linked pages work good but css does not. Also in the section where the recaptcha(I have a recaptcha script for the contact form) is, it shows a message `an internal error ocurred`. Everything works good when I change the DNS record to A and point to **`myserveripaddress`**, since it automatically redirects on port `80`.
 Of course every time I change the DNS record I change the listening ports on the Apache configuration file. Is it the URL frame DNS record affecting the importing of css files?I found a similar case in StackOverflow but the user found out it was something wrong in the code. In my case **it works good whenever I switch to port `80`**.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your styles are also in folder for site on port **8080**

And you don't need to change port on Apache. You can write `Listen <port>` command in httpd.conf twice:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

**UPDATE**

In your answer your pointed to incorrect `<base>` tag. Of course it will resolve your problem. From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp):

> The  tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.

So your default URL was set to 80 by `<base>` tag

Comment: Mixed up with ports: you said it did'n work on port 8080, but works on port 80. So you must check your folder for site on port **8080** for styles. Edited my answer

Comment: what do you mean?it's the same folder. I just change the listening ports on httpd.conf "Listen port" and "<VirtualHost *:port>". Sorry I don't understand

Comment: So, you have one `<VirtualHost>` block, and you change it between `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:8080>`?

Comment: Just in case: don't you forget to reload Apache after http.conf change?

Comment: Correct. I do it whenever I change the listening port in httpd.conf. Otherwise it does not show the VirtuaHost document root but the actual server root.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML part where you include *.css and *.js?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen-sizes.css"> <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scripts.js"></script> and yes I reload Apache whenever I make any change

Comment: What's your browser console says about those CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the head I found that I had `<base href="http://MyDomainName.com/" />` and I replaced with `<base href="/" />` somehow it had something to do with the full URL. It did worked like that on port 80 tough...weird. Now it works good. Thanks to Sergey Maksimenko for indirectly pushing me to take a look to the head tags.